# Can ReSharper insert blank lines after single line comments?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, resharper

Are there any code formatting options in ReSharper to make this:

```
public string PublicMethod1(string parameter)
{
    // Comment
    parameter += "Hello";

    // Comment
    parameter += " ";

    // Comment
    parameter += "world";
    parameter += "!";
    return parameter;
}
```

look like this:

```
public string PublicMethod1(string parameter)
{
    // Comment

    parameter += "Hello";

    // Comment

    parameter += " ";

    // Comment

    parameter += "world";
    parameter += "!";
    return parameter;
}
```

I am currently using Visual Studio Professional 2019 (16.11.9) and ReSharper 2021.3.2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, unfortunately you can only do that *before* a comment...**

From .editorconfig:

`resharper_blank_lines_before_single_line_comment`

From options:

[image]